# Problems changing 'is' dynamically in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to add a Polymer UI to an existing HTML page which contains a form. I don't have control over the content of the page, only the header and footer, so I can't change the form to use Polymer elements rather than `<input>`. So instead I'm trying to rewrite the form using Javascript.

I'm finding that adding an `is` attribute to an existing element has no effect --- the element doesn't get upgtaded.

I presume that this is all happening at a point after which Polymer has scanned the DOM looking for `is` attributes, so it's not noticing my change. (Although creating a new element with an `is` attribute and adding it also doesn't work, which is kind of weird, because adding a Polymer custom element *does* work.)

Is there any way around this; such as telling Polymer when I add the new element so that it can be upgraded properly?

Comment: _is_ should be used on polymer elements, not regular forms or controls. polymer elements are "upgraded" on creation only. just swap out the existing elements with new custom tags, and everything should work fine.

Comment: I don't know _Polymer_, but I'll point out that anything that causes a re-interpretation of _HTML_ (from a _String_, e.g. `.innerHTML`) destroys all the previous elements and their properties. You may be encountering this effect.

Comment: @dandavis: that's not what the docs say --- see https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-input. And I can't use custom tags because then the form stops working.

Comment: @DavidGiven: you're right, polymer has veered away from the standards since i last checked in, and seems to be scanning. you might be able to use Polymer.mixin(), but i'm not sure; polymer seems to have gotten really complicated recently, which is a shame. are you wanting to use your own custom elements, or are you just looking to drop-in the pretty paper controls? if the later, you might look into bootswatch's paper theme, and if the former, look into xtags or veneer. there's another one with a funny name i don't recall, bojangles or something...

Comment: @dandavis that's not correct. Polymer hasn't steered away from the standards here. `is=` are called type extension custom elements, are part of the spec, and are used to instantiate a custom element that inherits from a native one. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#usetypeextension

Comment: @ebidel: forgive my ignorance; those details seem important and under-published, especially compared to say, doc.regElm()...

Answer (score 2):

To use `is=`, you must be extending a native element. These are called type extension custom elements (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#usetypeextension).

In general, I don't believe adding the `is=` attribute at a later time has any effect on upgrading the element. The element needs to be declared up front with `is=` (e.g. `<input is="core-input">`) or instantiated dynamically using the special version of createElement:

```
var input = document.createElement('input', 'core-input');
```

In the declared case, this is the parsers signal to alter the prototype of the element when it's seen. In the JS case, that's done at creation time. If you just use `el.setAttribute('is', 'core-input')`, the element's prototype is already created by that point so it has no effect.

Comment: This _is_ a native element --- it's an `<input>`. Do you have a reference on the second part? It's not that I don't believe you, but it seems to violate HTML's ability to incrementally construct DOM hierarchies, and I want to know whether this is a fundamental problem with HTML or just a bug in Polymer.

Comment: It appears that data-binding the "is" attribute also doesn't work. Either Polymer doesn't support it, or it doesn't work inside a repeating template.
Note: I have also tried binding with "is$={{customElement}}". Even if the attribute appears with the correct value in the DOM, it still won't bind the element.